# Scrapy: crawling a google play app page with the reviews

Tags: python, scrapy, google-play, web-crawler

I'm trying to get details of some apps with their reviews. The problem is that I don't know how to associate each app's details with its reviews. Here is a code sample:

```
def parse(self, response):
    l = ItemLoader(item=GamesScraperItem(), response=response)
    #Get the details of the app here 
    #...

    url = "https://play.google.com/store/getreviews"
    #...        
    for num in range(111):   
        form_data = {"id": _id, "reviewType": '0', "reviewSortOrder": '4', "pageNum": str(num),"xhr": '1'}
        sleep(5)
        yield FormRequest(url=url,headers=headers_data, formdata=form_data,callback=self.parse_reviews)

def parse_reviews(self, response):     
    response_data = re.findall("\[\[.*", response.body) 
    if response_data:
        try:
            text = json.loads(response_data[0] + ']')               
            sell = Selector(text=text[0][2])
        except:
            pass
        #Get a list of reviews data
        #...
```

I would like to find a way to join all the reviews in one list and then add it to the details of the app.

Thanks.

Comment: you shouldn't use `time.sleep` scrapy is asynchronious and it just blocks everything, Try [`download_delay` setting](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can carry your item over in `Request.meta` attribute.

```
def parse(self, response):
    l = ItemLoader(item=GamesScraperItem(), response=response)
    #Get the details of the app here 
    url = "https://play.google.com/store/getreviews"
    form_data = {"id": _id, "reviewType": '0', "reviewSortOrder": '4', "pageNum": "1","xhr": '1'}
    yield FormRequest(url=url, 
                      headers=headers_data, 
                      formdata=form_data,
                      callback=self.parse_reviews
                      meta={'item': l.load_item()})  # <---

def parse_reviews(self, response):     
    item = response.meta['item'] # <---
    l = ItemLoader(item=item, response=response)
    # add more stuff to the loader, it will have everything that was added in parse method
    # ...
    # do page 2 the same way you did page 1 in parse method
    form_data = {"id": _id, "reviewType": '0', "reviewSortOrder": '4', "pageNum": "2","xhr": '1'}
```